# Replacing colors in a logo to match site colors

Tags: colors, image-editing, processing, image-processing, paint.net

I am working on trying to update the website for our organization. We are Tech Coordinators for school districts in Mississippi. I am not artistic, but I wanted to take a little time and try to change things up on our website. http://www.metla.org

I have no idea where our original logo came from, but we don't have a high resolution image, so I am having some difficulty changing up the colors. I would like to get them to match the changes I have made on the site, and I think Paint .NET will do this for me, but the suggestions for Hue/Saturation settings has not helped. Any ideas?

[METLA Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qvVbZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can look into a more powerful open source image editor.

I've had a lot of success with [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/).

The alternative is to outright make a new logo instead of trying to match to your old logo.  You can use the old logo as a template, redo it in high resolution, and just pick the colors that matches your new website.